# A case for multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Say I have a function that gives me a lot of data coming from a device when called. I want to accumulate this data in a memory buffer. When the buffer reaches an arbitrarily chosen length, another function jumps in, takes the buffer and performs some operation on it. The stream of data should not stop, so I am thinking of running this function in a separate process or thread.

A quick draft would look something like this (without threading or multiprocessing implemented):

```
def get_data():
    getting data...

def get_bufferchunk():
    get the current buffer and do something...

buffer = []

while True:
   
   data = get_data()
   buffer.append(data)
   
   if len(data) == 100000:
      get_bufferchunk(buffer)
      buffer = []
```

So the function `get_bufferchunk()` should then run in a parallel process, so that the while loop can keep running and the data stream does not get blocked.

My question if this is a reasonable idea and if so one would use multiprocessing or threading for this purpose? I only see the issue, that one has to make sure that the code inside the function gets executed faster than the buffer refilling to 1000000 values.

Comment: If the data can be expressed as an array of a ctypes type you can use multiprocessing with [shared ctypes objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects) to create the buffer. If "get_data" mainly waits for IO-operations then threading may be enough instead.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Could you maybe elaborate a little bit more on this ctypes? Never heard of this. A first look at the link does not help me much to understand the concept.

Comment: The standard library also has its own "ctypes" module. "ctypes" is made to call functions in compiled libraries and provides basic and compound data types known from the C language.

Answer (score 0):

The comment offered by Michael Butscher, if I understand it correctly, is suggesting that you implement the `buffer` object as a shared memory type, perhaps a `multiprocessing.sharedctypes.RawArray` of some suitable type. In that way, data can be passed between processes very efficiently since the data resides in shared memory and both processes can directly "see" the data without having to pass it from one address space to another. But the `RawArray` class only supports a limited number of data types it can hold, which may or may not be an issue for you. Also, you need to come up with a way of allowing the process that is collecting the data to continue to add data to the array while the other process is processing the data. This could get rather complicated.

So I would first try to pass to each process a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance. When `get_bufferchunk` gets a full buffer (and this can just be an ordinary list), it then does a `put` of the buffer to the queue. The other process, represented for example by worker function `process_bufferchunk` loops doing calls to `get` on the queue to retrieve the next buffer and process it. Depending on the type of data `buffer` is holding and what sort of processing is done by `process_bufferchunk`, how fast the data is coming in via `get_data`, etc. I would adjust accordingly what length of  `buffer` triggers a `put` to the queue.

This is the general idea:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def get_data():
    return 1

def get_bufferchunk(q):
    # get the current buffer and do something...

    buffer = []

    # So we eventually terminate:
    #while True:
    for _ in range(600_000):
        data = get_data()
        buffer.append(data)

        if len(buffer) == 100_000: # or a smaller chunk, for example 1000
            q.put(buffer)
            buffer = []
    # tell other process that there is no more data coming
    q.put(None)

def process_bufferchunk(q):
    while True:
        buffer = q.get()
        if buffer is None: # Sentinel?
            # Yes: Signal for us to terminate:
            break
        # For demo purposes just print the length:
        print('Buffer length = ', len(buffer))

def main():
    q = Queue()
    p1 = Process(target=get_bufferchunk, args=(q,))
    p2 = Process(target=process_bufferchunk, args=(q,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
Buffer length =  100000
Buffer length =  100000
Buffer length =  100000
Buffer length =  100000
Buffer length =  100000
Buffer length =  100000
```

Comment: Wow nice thank you! I will give it a try but maybe I'll come back to you.